# Finding the Lyapunov function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, stability-in-odes, lyapunov-functions

I have the following system of ODEs.

\begin{equation}
\dot{x} = -x + 4y
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\dot{y} = -x - y^3
\end{equation}

Typically, I have seen the first standard guess to be $V(x) = x^2 + y^2$. However, my lecturer opted to use $$V(x) = x^2 + 4 \cdot y^2$$ I am unsure why or how he knew to chose that particular one which is slightly different to the standard guess. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a,b$ positive real numbers. Multiplying the first equation by $2ax$, the second one by $2by$, and summing altogether we get
$$2ax\dot{x}+2by\dot{y} = -2ax^2 + 8axy -2byx - 2by^4$$
that is
$$\dot{V}(x,y)=-2(ax^2 +by^4)+2(4a-b)xy.$$
where $V(x,y)=ax^2+by^2$.

Notice that the $xy$ term, which changes sign in a neighborhood of the origin, disappears as soon as $4a=b$ and we obtain that for any
$(x,y)\not=(0,0)$,
$$\dot{V}(x,y)=-2a(x^2 +4y^4)< 0$$
with $V(x,y)=a(x^2+4y^2)$.

Comment: why do you multiply the first equation by $2x$ and the second by $2my$, not the other way round, swapping $x$ and $y$ of course. Doesn't your method assume that the Lyapunov function is in the form: $V(x,y) = x^2 + my^2$? And if this is the case how did you know that?

Comment: @HarrySpratt We may start by trying to find $V$ of the form $ax^2+by^2$ with $a,b>0$. Is it a reasonable choice?

Comment: sorry for that pernickety point, that clears it up completely.